# React Failed to Compile (Linter)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint

I am having a series of bugs when attempting to "npm run build" my application

The first error I received was:

```
Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'value' of null
Occurred while linting /filepath
```

After some research I learned I was using an outdated babel-eslint and upgraded to '@babel/eslint-parser' and '@babel/core' v7.23.3. and in my eslintrc.json I added:

```
"parserOptions":{
  "ecmaVersion":12,
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "requireConfigFile": false
},

"plugins":[
  "react",
  "jest",
  "@babel"
]
```

This seemed to fix the problem however now the error I am getting is:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Error: [BABEL] /opt/project/src/index.jsx: @babel/helper-compilation-targets: 'opera_mobile' is not a valid target
- Did you mean 'opera'?
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have `browserslist` in your package.json? If you do, what happens if you remove this and then try to compile again?